# Getting Json From Wordpress Article URL

Tags: android, json, wordpress

I'm trying to get Json from Wordpress article URL, To note I'm not good in Json at all, and found some codes, Using those codes i was able to get posts and so on, but what i want is to get info from a article url, not the main page of the website, Using this code i'm getting errors like (no value), or can't get json, because the code isn't correct .

URL : "http://thinkdroid.net/5-ways-to-root-your-device/?json=1"

Code :

```
public class Task extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        JSONObject json = getJSONFromUrl(URL);
        parseJson(json);
        return "Something";
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
    }
}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
    Log.v("INFO", "Requesting: " + url);
    JSONObject jObj = null;
    String json = null;

    // Making HTTP request
    StringBuffer chaine = new StringBuffer("");
    try {
        java.net.URL urlCon = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlCon
                .openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Universal/2.0 (Android)");
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();

        //InputStream inputStream;
        //if(connection.getResponseCode() >= HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST)
        //  inputStream = connection.getErrorStream();
        //else
        //  inputStream= connection.getInputStream();
        Log.v("INFO", "ResponseCode: " + connection.getResponseCode());

        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                inputStream));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            chaine.append(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // writing exception to log
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    json = chaine.toString();

    Log.v("INFO", "Step 1, got Respons");

    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}

public void parseJson(JSONObject json) {
    try {
        // parsing json object
        if (json.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("ok")) {
                try {
                    JSONObject post = (JSONObject) getJSONFromUrl(URL);
                    PostItem item = new PostItem();
                    String Author = "";
                    if (post.has("author")) {
                        Object author = post.get("author");
                        if (author instanceof JSONArray
                                && ((JSONArray) author).length() > 0) {
                            author = ((JSONArray) author).getJSONObject(0);
                        }

                        if (author instanceof JSONObject
                                && ((JSONObject) author).has("name")) {
                            author = (((JSONObject) author)
                                    .getString("name"));
                        }
                        Author = author.toString();
                    }
                    Log.i("YPPPPPP2","ID " + post.getInt("id") + " TITLE " + Html.fromHtml(post.getString("title"))
                            .toString() + " Date " + post.getString("date") + " Tags " + ((JSONObject) post.getJSONArray("tags").get(0)).getString("slug") + " Author "+Author + " Content: " + post.getString("content"));
                    // TODO do we dear to remove catch clause?
                    try {
                        boolean thumbnailfound = false;

                        if (post.has("thumbnail")) {
                            String thumbnail = post.getString("thumbnail");
                            if (thumbnail != "") {
                                item.setThumbnailUrl(thumbnail);
                                thumbnailfound = true;
                            }
                        }

                        if (post.has("attachments")) {

                            JSONArray attachments = post
                                    .getJSONArray("attachments");

                            // checking how many attachments post has and
                            // grabbing the first one
                            if (attachments.length() > 0) {
                                JSONObject attachment = attachments
                                        .getJSONObject(0);

                                item.setAttachmentUrl(attachment
                                        .getString("url"));

                                // if we do not have a thumbnail yet, get
                                // one now
                                if (attachment.has("images")
                                        && !thumbnailfound) {

                                    JSONObject thumbnail;
                                    if (attachment.getJSONObject("images")
                                            .has("post-thumbnail")) {
                                        thumbnail = attachment
                                                .getJSONObject("images")
                                                .getJSONObject(
                                                        "post-thumbnail");

                                        item.setThumbnailUrl(thumbnail
                                                .getString("url"));
                                    } else if (attachment.getJSONObject(
                                            "images").has("thumbnail")) {
                                        thumbnail = attachment
                                                .getJSONObject("images")
                                                .getJSONObject("thumbnail");

                                        item.setThumbnailUrl(thumbnail
                                                .getString("url"));
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}`
```

Can you please help in it ?

Comment: what exactly do you want to fetch from the url you poster?

Comment: title, id, url, content, tags ..etc, for start only title .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
public void parseJson(JSONObject json) {
    ...
    JSONObject post = (JSONObject) getJSONFromUrl(URL);
    ...
}
```

You have to use `JSONObject post = json.getJSONObject("post");` instead